# Director.js routing library firing all route handler at the time of initialization

Tags: javascript, routes, url-routing, router

I am trying to use [directorjs](https://github.com/flatiron/director) routing library. I used the example provided at github as a reference. But it is firing all the call back handler at the time of initialization.

```
           var initializeRoutes = function(){  
               var routes = {
                   '/home': launchModule("Home"),
                   '/confirmation': launchModule("Confirmation")
               };
               var router = Router(routes);
               router.init("/home");

           } ;

            var launchModule = function(moduleKey){
                ReportMailer.Utils.ModuleLoader.launchModule(moduleKey);
            };
```

Scenario : Launch #/home works fine. But when I click a button to navigation to confirmation route, window location hash changes but didn't fire the call back handler.

To my amusement I found that all the callbacks are called at the time of initialization.
Please help.

Comment: Solved. It was not director library issue, but I was not returning closure. Because of which launchModule was returning value instead of returning callback.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the functions in your example. Change them to

```
var routes = {
               '/home': function() { launchModule("Home") },
               '/confirmation': function() { launchModule("Confirmation") }
             };
```